# appium nodejs (wd) hangs if element is not found

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mocha.js, appium

I run into a problem while using appium + nodejs (wd) + mocha, because I have a loading view (blackbox testing & I'm not the android app developer) and I want to wait for it's disapearment. So I tried something like this:

```js
wd.addPromiseChainMethod('waitForElementByIdDisappears', function (id, retries) {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (function waitForElementDisappears(retry, context){
            if(retry < 0) {
              return reject();
            }
            else {
              try {
                context.elementByIdIfExists(id, function(err, element) {
                  console.log('Element found: ' + element + ' retry: ' + retry);
                  if(typeof element === 'undefined') {
                    return resolve();
                  }
                  else {
                    setTimeout(() => waitForElementDisappears(retry-1, context), 1000);
                  }                  
                });
              }
              catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return reject();
              }
            }
        })(retries, self);
    });
});
```

Everything works fine until the loading view disapears, because then nodejs starts to hang with appium standalone console output:

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=de.myapp.foo:id/loadingView]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=de.myapp.foo:id/loadingView]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)

repeating over and over until it runs in it's timeout.

I also tried:

`hasElementById(value, cb) -> cb(err, boolean)`

`elementByIdOrNull(value, cb) -> cb(err, element)`

`elementsById(value, cb) -> cb(err, element)`
 (and check for element list empty)

and other syntactic ways like:

`context.elementByIdIfExists(id).then(element => { ... })`

But everytime my output was something like:

```
Element found: 15 retry: 30
Element found: 15 retry: 29
Element found: 15 retry: 28
Element found: 15 retry: 27

# hangs because the loading view was disappeared and appium standalone starts to repeat the [debug][info] section above ...
```

Thanks for reading & help!

Answer (score 0):

I previously used appium standalone and now changed to the latest npm appium version 1.6.x.But finally the setting of `.setImplicitWaitTimeout(250)` before my method and reset it after that method did the trick for me.